# How to remove unwanted attributes after using Xmlnclude?

Tags: c#, xml-namespaces, xmlserializer

I'm trying to serialise to the following XML:

```
...
<ManifestHeader>
    <Party Role="CHARGE">
        <f:Name>Name1</f:Name>
        ...
    </Party>
    <Party Role="SENDER">
        <Name>Name2</Name>
        ...
    </Party>
</ManifestHeader>
...
```

But I'm getting some unwanted attributes:

```
<ManifestHeader>
    <Party d4p1:type="PickupParty" Role="CHARGE" xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <f:Name>Name1</f:Name>
        ...
```

**How do I get rid of the `d4p1:type` and `xmlns:d4p1` attributes?**

I have an abstract class `AParty` with two subclasses `ChargeParty` and `SenderParty`.

In my `ManifestHeader` class I have:

```
    [XmlElement("Party")]
    public AParty[] Parties;
```

I use `XmlInclude` as follows:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(PickupParty))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SenderParty))]
```

In my serialzer I use a custom namespace:

```
serialiser.Serialize(file, this, nameSpace);
```

Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

I checked out [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9392555/1438809) before posting my question.  Firstly I'm using `XmlSerializer` not `DataContractSerializer`, and secondly I've successfully set the namespace for all of my objects **except** for those I've included with `XmlInclude`.  Hence this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove "d1p1" namespace prefix in DataContractSerializer XML output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392555/remove-d1p1-namespace-prefix-in-datacontractserializer-xml-output)

Comment: @erem I don't reckon it's a duplicate, see my edit.

Comment: Do you also need to deserialize?

Comment: @dbc Nah, only need to serialize.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of those attributes?

Comment: I'm trying to import to an application via XML, so I'm following the specification for their XML import file.  Their specification doesn't include the attributes, so I didn't want them either.  Hm, I never actually considered just leaving them in and seeing whether it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute [`"{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type), which usually appears with the prefix "`xsi:type`", is a standard way for a polymorphic element to explicitly assert its type.  `XmlSerializer`  uses it to [determine the type to deserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- and thus writes it during *serialization* for use later.

There's no trivial way to suppress output of the type while keeping the *same element name* for each polymorphic type.  (It would be easy if you had a different element name for each subclass of `AParty`, but you don't.)  The best option would be for `ManifestHeader` to implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You don't fully specify the `ManifestHeader`, so consider the following example:

```
[XmlRoot("ManifestHeader", Namespace = ManifestHeader.XmlNamespace)]
public class ManifestHeader : IXmlSerializable
{
    public const string XmlNamespace = "MyNamespace";

    public static XmlSerializerNamespaces GetXmlSerializerNamespaces()
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ManifestHeader.XmlNamespace);
        return ns;
    }

    // Some example properties

    public string AProperty { get; set; }

    public string ZProperty { get; set; }

    // The list of parties.

    public AParty[] Parties { get; set; }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        var ns = GetXmlSerializerNamespaces();
        writer.WriteElementString("ZProperty", ZProperty);
        foreach (var value in Parties)
        {
            XmlSerializationHelper.SerializeElementTo(value, "Party", ManifestHeader.XmlNamespace, writer, ns);
        }
        writer.WriteElementString("AProperty", AProperty);
    }
    #endregion
}

public abstract class AParty
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public abstract string Role { get; set; } // Returns a constant string; setter does nothing.
}
```

This manually serializes the properties of `ManifestHeader` (if any), loops through the elements of the `Party` array and serializes each, replacing their element names with `"Party"`.

It uses the following helper methods.  Note that, if one is to override the root element name using the [`XmlSerializer(Type, XmlRootAttribute)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1wczcys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor, one *must* [cache the serializer in a hash table to avoid a horrible memory leak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static void SerializeElementTo<T>(T value, string elementName, string elementNamespace, XmlWriter writer, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        var serializer = XmlSerializerRootAttributeCache.DemandSerializer(value.GetType(), elementName, elementNamespace);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value, ns);
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return GetXml(obj, false);
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, bool omitNamespace)
    {
        return GetXml(obj, new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()), omitNamespace);
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer)
    {
        return GetXml(obj, serializer, false);
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, bool omitStandardNamespaces)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = null;
        if (omitStandardNamespaces)
        {
            ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
        }
        return GetXml(obj, serializer, ns);
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    " }; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        return GetXml(obj, new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()), ns);
    }
}

public static class XmlSerializerRootAttributeCache
{
    readonly static Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, XmlSerializer> cache;
    readonly static object padlock = new object();

    static XmlSerializerRootAttributeCache()
    {
        cache = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, XmlSerializer>();
    }

    static XmlSerializer CreateSerializer(Type rootType, string rootName, string rootNamespace)
    {
        return new XmlSerializer(rootType, new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = rootName, Namespace = rootNamespace });
    }

    public static XmlSerializer DemandSerializer(Type rootType, string rootName, string rootNamespace)
    {
        var key = Tuple.Create(rootType, rootName, rootNamespace);
        lock (padlock)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer;
            if (!cache.TryGetValue(key, out serializer))
                serializer = cache[key] = CreateSerializer(rootType, rootName, rootNamespace);
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a simple test case:

```
[XmlRoot("ChargeParty", Namespace = ManifestHeader.XmlNamespace)]
[XmlType("ChargeParty", Namespace = ManifestHeader.XmlNamespace)]
public sealed class ChargeParty : AParty
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public override string Role
    {
        get
        {
            return "CHARGE";
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }

    public bool IsCharging { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("SenderParty", Namespace = ManifestHeader.XmlNamespace)]
[XmlType("SenderParty", Namespace = ManifestHeader.XmlNamespace)]
public sealed class SenderParty : AParty
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public override string Role
    {
        get
        {
            return "SENDER";
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }

    public string SenderName { get; set; }
}

public static class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var manifest = new ManifestHeader
        {
            AProperty = "A property",
            ZProperty = "Z Property",
            Parties = new AParty[] { new SenderParty { SenderName = "Sender Name" }, new ChargeParty { IsCharging = true }, new SenderParty { SenderName = "Another Sender Name" }, new SenderParty { SenderName = "Yet Another Sender Name" }, new ChargeParty { IsCharging = false } }
        };
        var xml = manifest.GetXml(ManifestHeader.GetXmlSerializerNamespaces());
        Debug.WriteLine(xml);
    }
}
```

Which produces:

> ```
> <ManifestHeader xmlns="MyNamespace">
>     <ZProperty>Z Property</ZProperty>
>     <Party Role="SENDER">
>         <SenderName>Sender Name</SenderName>
>     </Party>
>     <Party Role="CHARGE">
>         <IsCharging>true</IsCharging>
>     </Party>
>     <Party Role="SENDER">
>         <SenderName>Another Sender Name</SenderName>
>     </Party>
>     <Party Role="SENDER">
>         <SenderName>Yet Another Sender Name</SenderName>
>     </Party>
>     <Party Role="CHARGE">
>         <IsCharging>true</IsCharging>
>     </Party>
>     <AProperty>A property</AProperty>
> </ManifestHeader>
> ```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer!  I've tried running your solution in it's own project, but in the line `var xml = manifest.GetXml(ManifestHeader.GetXmlSerializerNamespaces());` I get an error:  `Error 1 'XmlSerialisation.ManifestHeader' does not contain a definition for 'GetXml' and no extension method 'GetXml' accepting a first argument of type 'XmlSerialisation.ManifestHeader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\ws\XmlSerialisation\XmlSerialisation\Program.cs 61 32 XmlSerialisation`.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Felix - that's an extension method I use for serializing to XML for testing purposes.  Included it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround, not really a solution.

Instead of using a base class and subclasses I used just a single big class, which avoids the need for `XmlInclude`, which avoids the unwanted attributes (`d4p1:type` and `xmlns:d4p1`).

The single big class I'm using basically has all the properties of the previous subclasses combined.  Depending on which role the class is, only a subset of properties are use.

This is pretty ugly, so if anyone has a proper solution that'd be mean!